# Wikileaks Vault 7 'WheepingAngel' SmartTV Malware

Tags: malware, cve

I investigated a little about the WheepingAngel Malware that was recently  leaked due the 'Vault 7 CIA Leaks' by Wikileaks. What i couldn't find where the actual CVEs that enable WheepingAngel to infect a SmartTV. Also i couldn't find any list of vulnerable SmartTVs.

Has anybody investigated this into detail and can tell me more about it?

E.g.:

- CVEs involved
- Source Code
- Vulnerable Devices
- Functionalities

  - e.g.: there was something about resetting the malware to 'factory settings' by pressing `<MUTE> 184 <POWEROFF>` when the infected device is in standby mode.
- Control-Mechanisms
- Weaknesses

  - e.g.: for Samsung SmartTV devices a update by Samsung disables *parts* or the whole malware.

Comment: Since there is not a lot of discussion going on, i will ivestigate further and answer it myself in the comming days.. :)

Comment: I'm curious, did you come to any conclusions?

Comment: not really, as there seems to be really few information about this destinct topic in the internet.  i guess that is because of the importance/serverity of such informations on the processes of the CIA/NSA/Homeland.. whoever uses this 'software'. Delicate topic, for sure.

Comment: No wonder considering the possible scope..

Comment: @SirMuffington exactly. maybe im gonna do some research again, its pretty interesting.